# can't install xampp-linux-5.5.30-6-installer.run in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lamp

i'm trying to install xampp-linux-5.5.30-6-installer.run on my ubuntu 14.04. it requires root permission and ask me to become a super user.
please help me to solve this advance

Comment: try with sudo ./xampp-linux-5.5.30-6-installer.run

Comment: i was placed this file in downloads after running the above command it says command not found .please tell me briefly i'm new one to ubuntu

Comment: cd ~/Downloads then try

Comment: sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop, sudo rm -rf /opt/lampp and rm -rf ~/.lampp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to download directory

> cd ~/Downloads

Change permission

> chmod 755 xampp-linux-*-installer.run

Run the installer

> sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run

See more [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html)